# Xamarin CrossMediaManager

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-mediaplayer

I am currently trying to utilize the Xamarin [CrossMediaManager](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager) but there seems to be a problem regarding reading source from the apps internal storage. The source i'm trying to access is : `/data/user/0/com.pickle.solenya/files/video/180724-084223550.mp4` This is my app package, and the location is an internal one.

I have tried a with a android content provider and accessing the file from `files://` and `content://` but without success.

The file does exist, and i have tried with other files, the file is found but the MediaPlayer either returns `E/MediaPlayer(12941): Error (-38,0)` or throws `java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000 | SecurityException`

More details around the thrown exceptions:

```
Couldn't open content://com.pickle.jaguar/video/180724-084223550.mp4: java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
07-24 14:21:47.367 D/MediaPlayer(10784): setDataSource IOException | SecurityException happend : 
07-24 14:21:47.367 D/MediaPlayer(10784): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
```

Requesting the following permissions at app start:

- android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
- android.permission.CAMERA
- android.permission.INTERNET
- android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
- android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL
- android.permission.WAKE_LOCK

Comment: Have you requested permissions correctly in your app?

Comment: I believe so, according to the documentation and notorious stack overflow research